# how to shift from first index value to third or fourth in nsarray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

i have two NSArray, First NSArray contain 20 objects and second NSArray contain 8 objects and i merge these array through a button like:

```
-(IBAction)AskhimChoice1:(id)sender {

  _combineArray =[_pageImages arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:_pageImages2];

}
```

problem is that when i press the button that also shift to the second array means shift index 20 to index21 after clicking the button.
hope you understand.

remember: _combineArray in also NSArray.

Comment: can you explain it clearly I am not getting what exactly happen there

Comment: what is the problem? can't understand your question. explain clearly.

Comment: problem is  when i press button that should be go to next array index mean at 21 but that doesn't go.

Comment: i add button at the  last index of first array as a subview.